# PHP Regex Question with preg_replace

Tags: php, regex

Okay, so say I have a string "!!test" or "!!!!!  testing".

What I want to be able to do is use preg_replace() and only keep the first "!" but keep the rest of the text after that first "!" that is not a "!"

"!!test" -> "!test"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = preg_replace('/!+/', '!', $str);
```

Replace multiple `!`s with a single `!`.

http://www.regular-expressions.info/ has some great tutorials and references for learning regular expressions.

Comment: Maybe you should add a ^ at the beginning of the regexp since the question was about the "firsts" !

Comment: @MaxiWheat I think that was just a way of explaining the concept of paring multiple `!`s down to one. If the OP requires that only one group of `!`s be replaced and that group is guaranteed to be at the beginning of the string, then yes, I'd add a `^`.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('#!+\s?test#','!test', $subject);
```

Works for both examples.